# Where is codepage in Dts.Connections?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

The codepage is specified on a flat-file connection manager. In a Script Task, Dts.Connections are available. Where can I find the code page for the connection?

```
>Debug.Print Dts.Connections[0]
{Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.ConnectionManager}
    ConnectionString: "C:\\data\\in\\devl\\file001.txt"
    CreationName: "FLATFILE"
    DelayValidation: false
    Description: ""
    HasExpressions: false
    HostType: ConnectionManager
    ID: "{AA4BD889-B2B2-4920-98D2-0CAA6F3CD722}"
    InnerObject: {System.__ComObject}
    Name: "FFCM-in"
    OfflineMode: false
    Properties: {Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DtsProperties}
    ProtectionLevel: EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey
    Qualifier: ""
    Scope: Package
    Site: null
    SupportsDTCTransactions: false
    VariableDispenser: {Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.VariableDispenser}
    Variables: {Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Variables}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hm, you can try the following -- cast InnerObject to IDTSConnectionManagerFlatFile100 type, it can be found in Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper. Like in the following example:

```
IDTSConnectionManagerFlatFile100 ffParams;
ffParams = yourConnectionManager.InnerObject as IDTSConnectionManagerFlatFile100;
ffParams.CodePage // Property with your Codepage
```

Or you can check it from Connection Manager properties like:

```
yourConnectionManager.Properties["CodePage"].GetValue(yourConnectionManager).ToString()
```

Comment: I got ConnectionManager.Properties to work, but still not `IDTSConnectionManagerFlatFile100`. `>Debug.Print ffParams.CodePage
error CS1061: 'IDTSConnectionManagerFlatFile100' does not contain a definition for 'CodePage' and no accessible extension method 'CodePage' accepting a first argument of type 'IDTSConnectionManagerFlatFile100' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` I have added a reference to `Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap`, but still not working.

Comment: Strange... Please, replace `IDTSConnectionManagerFlatFile100` in the code by `ConnectionManagerFlatFileClass`. Or try the second method with the `Properties`.

Comment: It appears that `Dts.Connections[0].Innerobject` cannot be cast as an `IDTSConnectionManagerFlatFile100`.